# I need to crash partition on linux disk

Tags: linux, crash, disk, ext4, partition

It's possible to crash one partition?

> I need to crash one of the linux ext4 partition of one SD disk, to
>   check if, my script of crash recovery, working...
>
> all it's on same SD card (part1,2, 3) i need to crash the third
>   partition
>
> partition 1 and 2 it's mounted RO, partition 3 RW

thank's 
Gigi0ne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I should be posting this... To be run as root:

```
# note: very dangerous thing to do:
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda3 bs=1M
```

where `sda3` is the partition you need to "crash". `cat /proc/mounts` or `df` or `fdisk -l` can tell you which device you are looking for.

Comment: Didn't expect you were serious about this... `hdparm` also has some nice features; `man hdparm` says `--make-bad-sector
              Deliberately create a bad sector (aka. "media error") on the disk.  **EXCEPTIONALLY DANGEROUS. DO NOT USE THIS OPTION!!**` Maybe you should give it a try?

Comment: If you make the right sectors bad (i.e. all superblock copies) the partition will die for sure. Try `dumpe2fs /dev/sda3 | grep -i superblock`, it should give you all superblock copies.

Comment: yes.. it's ok.. but the dd... it's more... i don't know if it's possible to write... "bastard" thank's to all anyway...